# How to plot graph from a .mat file including a structure?

Tags: matlab

I have been given a .mat file which contains data related to some test measurements. I need to write a script in matlab so that i could plot the graph of the given data in Matlab. I have already loaded the file. The problem is that it is a structure of size 1*1. How could i see the data and then proceed further ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data is isnide the structure. E.g. `data=mystruct.myfield`. However youare the only one that knows how the structure or the field are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load the .mat you will notice that the struct is composed by field.
For instance if the struct is called "struct_loaded" and the field are called "field1" "field2" and "field3" , you can access to "field1" using the command "struct_loaded.field1". The same to access to the other two field, "struct_loaded.field2" and "struct_loaded.field3".

Comment: yes i got it. it works when i Access it with 'fieldName.structureElement.time/value'. This command plots me a graph for the givenvalues at the corresponding time.